# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException in Selenium Java Class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my program in Java Selenium to find broken links in a page

I am facing the SSLHandshake exception issue in line huc.connect() for the link https://www.zlti.com. But i am able to open the link in the browser

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

```
package Automate;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class BrokenLinks {

    private static WebDriver driver = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String homePage = "https://www.zlti.com";
        String url = "";
        HttpsURLConnection huc = null;
        int respCode = 200;

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");
        DesiredCapabilities handlSSLErr = new DesiredCapabilities();
        handlSSLErr.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(handlSSLErr);


        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get(homePage);

        List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

        Iterator<WebElement> it = links.iterator();


        while(it.hasNext()){

            url = it.next().getAttribute("href");

            System.out.println(url);

            if(url == null || url.isEmpty()){
System.out.println("URL is either not configured for anchor tag or it is empty");
                continue;
            }

            if(!url.startsWith(homePage)){
                System.out.println("URL belongs to another domain, skipping it.");
                continue;
            }

            try {
                huc = (HttpsURLConnection)(new URL(url).openConnection());

                huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

                huc.connect();

                respCode = huc.getResponseCode();

                if(respCode >= 400){
                    System.out.println(url+" is a broken link");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println(url+" is a valid link");
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

Error stack trace:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:162)
https://www.zlti.com/#
    at Automate.BrokenLinks.main(BrokenLinks.java:66)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
    ... 17 more
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
```

Comment: Error at which line? Update the question with the complete error stack trace

Comment: Error in line huc.connect() and updated the entire error stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this piece of code to make it work

```
try {
    SSLContext ssl_ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        TrustManager[ ] trust_mgr = new TrustManager[ ] {
    new X509TrustManager() {
       public X509Certificate[ ] getAcceptedIssuers() { return null; }
       public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[ ] certs, String t) { }
       public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[ ] certs, String t) { }
     }
  };
        ssl_ctx.init(null,                // key manager
                     trust_mgr,           // trust manager
                     new SecureRandom()); // random number generator
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(ssl_ctx.getSocketFactory());
    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Working code

```
package Automate;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class BrokenLinks {

    private static WebDriver driver = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String homePage = "https://resources.collab.net";
        String url = "";
        HttpsURLConnection huc = null;
        int respCode = 200;

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");
        DesiredCapabilities handlSSLErr = new DesiredCapabilities();
        handlSSLErr.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(handlSSLErr);

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get(homePage);

        List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

        Iterator<WebElement> it = links.iterator();
        try {
        SSLContext ssl_ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            TrustManager[ ] trust_mgr = new TrustManager[ ] {
        new X509TrustManager() {
           public X509Certificate[ ] getAcceptedIssuers() { return null; }
           public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[ ] certs, String t) { }
           public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[ ] certs, String t) { }
         }
      };
            ssl_ctx.init(null,                // key manager
                         trust_mgr,           // trust manager
                         new SecureRandom()); // random number generator
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(ssl_ctx.getSocketFactory());
        } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(it.hasNext()){

            url = it.next().getAttribute("href");

            System.out.println(url);

            if(url == null || url.isEmpty()){
System.out.println("URL is either not configured for anchor tag or it is empty");
                continue;
            }

            if(!url.startsWith(homePage)){
                System.out.println("URL belongs to another domain, skipping it.");
                continue;
            }

            try {
                huc = (HttpsURLConnection)(new URL(url).openConnection());

                huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

                huc.connect();

                respCode = huc.getResponseCode();

                if(respCode >= 400){
                    System.out.println(url+" is a broken link");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println(url+" is a valid link");
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

Comment: If you post the answer to your own question it is worth emphesizing what was the particular  change against the original code (not just posting the whole code itself) and why is it fixed the issue. This will make your question and your answer more valuable to others.